# KSOAP2 error does not contain source for the file HttpTransport.class

Tags: java, android, web-services, android-ksoap2

Trying to implement ksoap2 on android app with Eclipse (3.6).

This is the part of the source code:

```
SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
envelope.dotNet=true;
envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

HttpTransport androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransport(URL);
androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
```

When hitting the `androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);` line, I get an error saying:

> The source attachment does not contain source for the file HttpTransport.class

In the log I get this error:

> VFY: dead code 0x0005-0005 in Lorg/ksoap2/transport/ServiceConnectionMidp; .setRequestProperty (Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V

What the hell is the problem?

Comment: cheak your ksoap lib. it having httptransport class?

Comment: probably it's `HttpTransportSE`

Answer (score 0):

Use `HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransportSE=new HttpTransportSE(URL)`
in place of `HttpTransport`.

Probably this will resolve your problem.

Comment: i downloaded the ksoap-j2me-core-2.1.2.jar to import the classes but i checked its tree it doesnt have HttpTransportSE class!! where can i get it.. the tree of the exact same package on net says it has that class @

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is with HttpTransportSE, I am sure you can download ksoap2 with dependencies from the following page:
http://simpligility.github.io/ksoap2-android/getting-started.html

Comment: @Marko Popovic: The answer is not in the link. The link is just part of the answer.

Comment: @gariepy You guys are right, I did not pay enough attention. Sorry about that. I've deleted my suggestion for deletion of the answer.